# Turn PHP script into a MySQL procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a script in PHP that I need to turn into a MySQL procedure. I can't run the PHP script because this must be executed by a MySQL trigger. Because I have no idea how to fix this in all MySQL, I wrote it in PHP.

The PHP script below needs to be changed to a MySQL procedure. The `25` and `http://www.someurl.com/` are variables that filled from the trigger (`new.order_id` / `new.store_url`):

```
$query = "SELECT
            oc_order_product.quantity,
            oc_order_option.option_value_id,
            product.id
          FROM oc_order_product
            JOIN oc_order_option
              ON oc_order_option.order_id = oc_order_product.order_id
            JOIN product
              ON product.oc_product_id = oc_order_product.model
          WHERE oc_order_product.order_id = '25' AND oc_order_product.store_url = 'http://www.someurl.com/'";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
  $query = "UPDATE product_option_value SET quantity = quantity - {$row->quantity} WHERE product_id='{$row->id}' AND option_value_id='{$row->option_value_id}'";
  $mysqli->query($query);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql

Comment: @Dimitri I don't know how that question would help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oke, I found my own answer after reading the internet en doing some trail and error.

I created a stored procedure which I will execute on the update trigger.

**The trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `order_gereed` AFTER UPDATE ON `oc_order`
 FOR EACH ROW IF new.order_status_id = "15"
THEN
CALL VooraadUpdate(new.order_id, new.store_url);
UPDATE push_voorraad SET actie = '1';
END IF
```

**The procedure**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `VooraadUpdate`(IN `orderID` INT(11), IN `storeURL` VARCHAR(255))
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE a, b, c INT;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT
                              oc_order_product.quantity,
                              oc_order_option.option_value_id,
                              product.id
                            FROM oc_order_product
                              JOIN oc_order_option
                                ON oc_order_option.order_id = oc_order_product.order_id
                              JOIN product
                                ON product.oc_product_id = oc_order_product.model
                            WHERE oc_order_product.order_id = orderID AND oc_order_product.store_url = storeURL;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur1;
    read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH cur1 INTO a, b, c;
        IF done THEN
          LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

      UPDATE product_option_value SET quantity = quantity - a WHERE product_id=c AND option_value_id=b;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
END
```